# Scroll Background to a Fixed Position

Tags: background, scroll

I think the title of my question accurately describes what I think I want to know.

I would like to be able to emulate/reproduce the exact scrolling functionality of this site https://dotvita.com/.

It seems the background is fixed but only scrolls to a point. Or, more clearly, it scrolls simultaneously with the rest of the content but only to a point. When I looked at the html source, here is what I saw:

```
<body>
   <div id="background"></div>
<body>
```

and the CSS for the background is:

```
#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: -458px;
}
```

Can you guys tell me what is going on here? Does the above code produce what we see on that site or is there something else going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed something else going on in the background. It looks like they are using Jquery and perhaps a custom script to produce this effect.

For many browsers, you can inspect individual elements or the entire site and see what files are being used. In Google Chrome, you can do this by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+I and clicking the "Resources" tab. Here you can use the file tree on the left to go into Frames > [website name] > Scripts and see the various script files loaded up.

Here is the file that appears to be causing this cool effect:
https://dotvita.com/php/min/?f=js/core/jquery.retina.js,js/core/jquery.resize.js,js/core/jquery.equalHeights.js,libs/qtip/js/jquery.qtip.js,libs/colorbox/js/jquery.colorbox.js,js/plugins.js,js/script.js

In order for this to work, the site needs to have Jquery installed, which is this file:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

This has been an effect I've been meaning to recreate myself for a while now. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I really appreciate your insight and research. I'm going to play around with this over the next couple of days and see what I come up with. I will let you know what I find!